# How to map a parametrized enum from a generic type to another?

Tags: rust

If I have a type like `MyEnum<T>`, how can I map it in cases where not every variant is parameterized?

For example, I'd like to convert from `MyEnum<u32>` to `MyEnum<String>`:

```
enum MyEnum<T> {
    B,
    C,
    D(T),
}

fn trans(a: MyEnum<u32>) -> MyEnum<String> {
    match a {
        MyEnum::D(i) => MyEnum::D(i.to_string()),
        other_cases => other_cases,
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

This fails with:

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:8:9
   |
8  |         match a {
   |         ^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found u32
   |
   = note: expected type `MyEnum<std::string::String>`
   = note:    found type `MyEnum<u32>`
note: match arm with an incompatible type
  --> src/main.rs:10:28
   |
10 |             other_cases => other_cases,
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Instead of the `other_cases => other_cases` line, I tried this, also without success:

```
other_cases => {
    let o: MyEnum<String> = other_cases;
    o
}
```

Comment: `MyEnum<u32>`  and `MyEnum<String>` are two different types, so their variants are not interchangable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
macro_rules! partial_enum {
    ($name: ident, $some: ident, $($none: ident),+) => {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        enum $name<T> {
            $some(T),
            $($none),+
        }
        impl<T> $name<T> {
            fn convert<U>(self) -> Result<$name<U>, T> {
                match self {
                    $name::$some(x) => Err(x),
                    $($name::$none => Ok($name::$none)),+
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
partial_enum!(MyEnum, D, B, C);
fn trans(a: MyEnum<u32>) -> MyEnum<String> {
    let a_split: Result<MyEnum<String>, u32> = a.convert();
    match a_split {
        Ok(is_none) => is_none,
        Err(not_none) => MyEnum::D(not_none.to_string()),
    }
}
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", trans(MyEnum::D(13)));
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I'd create a `map` method on your enum:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyEnum<T> {
    B,
    C,
    D(T),
}

impl<T> MyEnum<T> {
    fn map<U>(self, f: impl FnOnce(T) -> U) -> MyEnum<U> {
        use MyEnum::*;

        match self {
            B => B,
            C => C,
            D(x) => D(f(x)),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let answer = MyEnum::D(42);
    let answer2 = answer.map(|x| x.to_string());
    println!("{:?}", answer2);
}
```

This is similar to existing `map` methods, such as [`Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map).

Answer (score 9):

Well, this is actually an answer:

```
enum MyEnum<T> {
    B,
    C,
    D(T),
}

fn trans(a: MyEnum<u32>) -> MyEnum<String> {
    match a {
        MyEnum::D(i) => MyEnum::D(i.to_string()),
        MyEnum::B => MyEnum::B,
        MyEnum::C => MyEnum::C
    }
}

fn main() {
}
```

But repeating all variants isn't acceptable when there's a lot of them..

Comment: This is exactly what you need to do. For large cases, you may be able to form a macro that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Some languages (like C++), use Duck Typing: if it quacks like a duck, it must be a duck, and therefore names matter. Rust does not.

In Rust, names are just some display utility for us mere humans, the `B` in `MyEnum<u32>` and `MyEnum<String>` may happen to have the same visual representation, but they are completely different syntactic entities as far as the language is concerned.

---

There are multiple ways to alleviate your pain, though:

- a code generation plugin or `build.rs` script can be used as well
- a macro can be used to automate the mapping
- a manual mapping can be done, it's a one shot effort after all
- the code can be restructured to separate type-dependent from type-independent variants

I'll show-case the latter:

```
enum MyEnumImpl {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

enum MyEnum<T> {
    Independent(MyEnumImpl),
    Dependent(T),
}
```

Obviously, the latter makes it much easier to manually map things.